# Custom Button from 9patches WITHOUT XML

Tags: java, android, button, mobile

I would like to create a custom Android button from 9patches, but without using any XML. I know, it sounds dumb, but the reason is that for some reason my IDE (NetBeans) messes up the whole XML beyond belief. The `R.java` doesn't get generated half the time (the fixes didn't work for me), and I get random errors, even if I just copy and paste XML from tutorials.

This is how I plan to create the Button:

1. The button has a `setBackgroundDrawable()` method
2. I need to suply this method with a `StateListDrawable`
3. Which I need to build up from `NinePatchDrawables`

So first I need to create the 9patches, then a `StateListDrawable` from them, and simply pass the `StateListDrawable` as background for my Button's `setBackgroundDrawable()` method.

I can't start the 9patches, because I can't find out how the constructors work.

Comment: Thank you, finally i was able to get an application running with a custom button. But there is another problem: android doesn't seem to recognize, that my drawables ara 9 patches. If i put more text in the button, it gets all messed up. I tried to explicitly cast the Drawables, when i load them from the resource files:

NinePatchDrawable normal = (NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_red_normal);

but then i get an error. Is there a way, to tell the compiler/android system/whoever does it, to handle my drawables as 9 patches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense for you to invest your time in either:

- fixing NetBeans, or
- switching to some different editor/IDE?

Trying to do Android development without XML is akin to trying to fly without wings. It's possible, but rockets tend to crash and burn in the end.

---

Regardless, you do not need to directly work with `NinePatchDrawable` to use nine-patch PNG files. Android will handle that part for you.

Instead, create an instance of `StateListDrawable` and call `addState()` for each one of your states. To get the `Drawable` for the state, use `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.this_is_one_of_your_nine_patch_images)` from your `Activity`. Android will detect that this is a nine-patch and will do the right thing.